# Generating a 2x3 Table with Column/Row Numbers in a nested for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a 2x3 table that has numbers for each column/row using a nested for loop.

My current output looks like this:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6
```

The final output should look like this:

```
    0  1  2
0   0  1  2
1   3  4  5
```

And here's my current code:

```
def main():
    li = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
    for row in li:
        for item in row:
            print(item, end=" ")
        print()
main()
input("\n\nPress Enter key to exit: ")
```

I appreciate any assistance with this problem.

Comment: Why would you expect the numbers printed to be `0,1,2`, `3,4,5` when you have `li = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and you're printing those numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate the output you have specified, but if it doesn't meet your requirements, you need to update your question to be more specific.

Assuming you do want the rows and columns numbered as you have shown, the particular part that you might, or might not, know is to use `enumerate` which will automatically generate the count of the number of `row` you are printing, to save you using a separate counter variable.

```py
def main():
    li = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
    print("    ", end="")
    for x in range(len(li[0])):
        print(x, end=" ")
    print()
    for index, row in enumerate(li):
        print(index, end="   ")
        for item in row:
            print(item - 1, end=" ")
        print()

main()
```

Output:

```
    0 1 2 
0   0 1 2 
1   3 4 5
```